# Casting removes all levels of Optional in Swift?

Tags: swift, casting, option-type

We all know that you can use *optional binding* to unwrap an optional:

```
let b: String? = "bye"

if let greeting = b {
    print(greeting)  // "bye"
}
```

But if the value has multiple levels of optionals, only one will be removed:

```
let b: String?? = "bye"
if let greeting = b {
    print(greeting)  // "Optional(bye)"
}
```

Casting the value to the underlying type will remove the double optional:

```
let b: String?? = "bye"
if let greeting = b as? String {
    print(greeting)  // "bye"
}
```

I was surprised to find this works for any level of optionals:

```
let b: String??????? = "bye"
print(b as Any)  // Optional(Optional(Optional(Optional(Optional(Optional(Optional("bye")))))))

if let greeting = b as? String {
    print(greeting)  // "bye"
}
```

Is there an explanation of why casting removes all levels of optionals?

Also:

```
let b: String??????? = "bye"
print(b as! String)  // "bye"
```

but it gives the humorous warning:

> Forced cast from 'String???????' only unwraps optionals; did you mean to use '!!!!!!!'.

Comment: Is it with Foundation import or pure Swift?

Comment: @Sulthan, pure Swift has the same behavior.

Comment: This is the one place that I hate about Swift - the lack of a good spec. The only official information I was able to find about this is https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TypeCasting.html but that is far from the formality in the Java or C# specifications. If Swift had a spec as good as those ones, I'm sure this behaviour will be documented there...

Comment: Did you consider asking on https://forums.swift.org/c/swift-users ?

Comment: Swift's runtime casting machinery can look through optional values to (recursively) perform casts on the payload value (it's actually [the very first thing it tries to do](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/78b5ff8b6b7b2cf54bd4e69fb1b059749ea50f6a/stdlib/public/runtime/Casting.cpp#L2408)).

Comment: Basically it's baked into the language. If you think about it, casting an Optional shouldn't be legal at all, but it gets a special behind-the-scenes dispensation to permit it. I dislike syntactic sugar and Swift is noteworthy for avoiding it, but casting of Optionals is certainly a case in point.

Answer (score 0):

It’s because in the structure `if let unwrapped = instance as? Type`, the right part is evaluated first. The full order is

1. Swift tries to cast instance to a `Type` by executing `instance as? Type`. The `as?` operator always does the following - if `instance` can be represented as `Type` then it casts it, otherwise it returns a `nil`. The important part is that the `as? Type` operator always returns an `Optional<Type>` regardless of the type of `instance`.
2. The `if let` operator, **which always unwraps only one level**, unwraps this `Optional<Type>` into a `Type`.

Comment: Sure, but the other option would have been for the  `as?` to return `nil` because the starting value wasn't an `Optional<String>`.  The part that I'm surprised about it that Swift does decide that `String???????` can be cast to `String`.

Comment: Yes, but with your code you’re not checking that b is Optional<String>, you’re just checking b can be represented as String, and I believe that all levels of Optional<Optional<...<String>>> can be casted to String, if they contain a value.

Comment: Apparently all levels of Optional<Optional<...<String>>> can be cast to String.  That is a surprising result to me and I've been looking at Swift since it first appeared in beta.  I wonder if this documented anywhere.